# ¿Cómo verificar si un recurso ha sido eliminado previamente antes de responder al front con Laravel?

Tags: laravel

¿Cómo puedo saber si un recurso de mi base de datos ha sido eliminado previamente antes de mandar una respuesta al front?

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código elimino un recurso y luego mando una respuesta satisfactoria pero, me gustaría comprobar antes el código de estatus http del servidor para poder responder de acuerdo a eso y no he encontrado la forma de poder acceder a ese estatus.

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $post->delete();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Eliminado correctamente'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Podrías consultar de nuevo la BD. Pero si `$post->delete();` no lanza una excepción es porque se eliminó correctamente

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Al momento de querer borrar un registro ya eliminado previamente, Laravel (la versión 9 al menos) responde al front con un documento html y lo que me gustaría es evitar eso enviando otro tipo de mensaje en formato json o algo similar, por ende lo que se me había ocurrido es ver si existe forma de capturar la respuesta http para saber si ya se eliminó o no previamente y responder de acuerdo a eso.

Comment: Ah, había entendido otra cosa. ¿Cómo estás enviando la petición? Si es via ajax, asegurate que tenga la cabecera Accept application/json. Si la petición la enviando con un form html tendrías que ir por algo como lo que se explica [aquí](https://laraveldaily.com/post/laravel-api-404-response-return-json-instead-of-webpage-error) (esto último no sé si sigue igual en la última versión, perl sería por ese lado)

Comment: Otra opción sería evitar directamente el model binding y hacer la consulta manualmente

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Excelente, me funcionó modificando la cabecera, ¡agradezco tu ayuda!

Comment: Vale. Por favor agrega una respuesta explicando como lo resolviste y marcala como aceptada cuando el sistema te lo permita. Así le puede servia a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Básicamente lo que hice fue modificar la cabecera. El atributo de Accept estaba configurado valor de */*, es decir que aceptaba todo según entiendo pero, al indicar que solo quiero aceptar archivos json con  application/json, Laravel lo interpreta y por ende manda ese tipo de archivos.